# Check if a string is encoded/quoted in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using a Python handler to respond to an HTTP API. I'm reading some url params into the handler. There are some params which needs mandatory encoded strings. How can I check if the value of certain parameter is a regular string or a encoded string?

`handler?u=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com` Pass.

vs

`handler?u=https://stackoverflow.com` Should fail as this is a plain string.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the string with its unquoted version:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> s1 = 'handler?u=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com'
>>> s2 = 'handler?u=https://stackoverflow.com'
>>> urlparse.unquote(s1) == s1
False
>>> urlparse.unquote(s2) == s2
True
```

Comment: Seems rather fragile to me: what a bout that case: `handler?u=https://my.proxy.to/https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com`

Comment: @Mathias `urlparse.unquote(s1) == s1` would return `False` (like in the "quoted" case of this answer). But I don't think the string I gave above was properly "encoded" according to the OP definition? Or is it?