# Python: unicode error when downloading a pdf from an url in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-lab

I have recently started my Python journey and stackoverflow has helped me a lot in resolving most of the issues I came across. However, this is one that I don't seem to be able to catch, despite trying the different solutions suggested here.

I am collecting urls from a website in a list. My next step is to go through the urls and download them if they don't already exist in the folder. However, some of the URLs contain non-ascii characters, such as ú, é, ç. Which leads to the unicode error below.

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfa' in position 64: ordinal not in range(128)

I escaped it for now with try/except but would need to download those manually.

When I use .encode('utf-8') it also result in an error: "TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object".

This is my code:

```
import os
import urllib

dict = (this includes a large dictionary scraped from a website)

links = []

for d in dict :
    links.append(d["EncodedAbsUrl"])
    
# For every line in the file

for url in links:
    # Split on the rightmost / and take everything on the right side of that
    name = url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]

    # Combine the name and the downloads directory to get the local filename
    filename = os.path.join(r'C:\\PATH', name)

    # Download the file if it does not exist
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)    
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            print(filename + " could not be saved.")
            pass
    else:
            print(filename + " already exists.")
```

### Edit

Based on Ardiya's suggestion in the comments (thanks a million for that), I have changed used the urllib.parse.quote_plus method. This seems to work but also returns an http error 400. Revised code now reads:

```
for url in links:
   # Split on the rightmost / and take everything on the right side of that
    name = url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    
    # Combine the name and the downloads directory to get the local filename
    filename = os.path.join(r'C:\\PATH', name)

    # Download the file if it does not exist
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)    
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            new_url = str(root + url.split('/')[-2] + '/' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(name))
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(new_url, filename)
    else:
            print(filename + " already exists.")
```

For example, the following link is in the source dictionary: `https://www4.unfccc.int/sites/ndcstaging/PublishedDocuments/Peru%20First/iNDC%20Perú%20castellano.pdf` is translated into `https://www4.unfccc.int/sites/ndcstaging/PublishedDocuments/Peru%20First/iNDC%2520Per%C3%BA%2520castellano.pdf` which does not properly work.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-12f5f676515d> in <module>
     25         try:
---> 26             urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
     27         except UnicodeEncodeError:

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    246 
--> 247     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
    248         headers = fp.info()

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    524         sys.audit('urllib.Request', req.full_url, req.data, req.headers, req.get_method())
--> 525         response = self._open(req, data)
    526 

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _open(self, req, data)
    541         protocol = req.type
--> 542         result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
    543                                   '_open', req)

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    501             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502             result = func(*args)
    503             if result is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in https_open(self, req)
   1392         def https_open(self, req):
-> 1393             return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
   1394                 context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1349             try:
-> 1350                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
   1351                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1254         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1255         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1256 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1265 
-> 1266         self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
   1267 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in putrequest(self, method, url, skip_host, skip_accept_encoding)
   1103 
-> 1104         self._output(self._encode_request(request))
   1105 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _encode_request(self, request)
   1183         # ASCII also helps prevent CVE-2019-9740.
-> 1184         return request.encode('ascii')
   1185 

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfa' in position 64: ordinal not in range(128)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-12f5f676515d> in <module>
     27         except UnicodeEncodeError:
     28             new_url = str(root + url.split('/')[-2] + '/' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(name))
---> 29             urllib.request.urlretrieve(new_url, filename)
     30     else:
     31             print(filename + " already exists.")

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    245     url_type, path = _splittype(url)
    246 
--> 247     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
    248         headers = fp.info()
    249 

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    638         # request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
--> 640             response = self.parent.error(
    641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500         for handler in handlers:
    501             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502             result = func(*args)
    503             if result is not None:
    504                 return result

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9345102/4400024

Comment: Hi Ardiya, thanks a lot for the quick reply. Based on your suggestion I changed the code. However, it results in another issue that I will add in the post above.

Comment: Please [edit] to include the full traceback in the question.

Comment: @Cantona86 you are quoting URL that's been quoted. see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25443334/4400024 to check whether you need to apply quote or not

Comment: Thanks, @tripleee, have added the traceback. Ardiya, sorry, I am trying to understand from the link you sent me, but it seems I am missing something (this is really my self-built python script).

Comment: The traceback indicates that the URL you passed in contains a literal `\xfa` character, completely unlike the URL in your question.

Comment: @tripleee This is the source:

` code`{"Title":"Peru First NDC (Archived)","Name":"iNDC Perú castellano.pdf","NDCNumber":"First","NDCISO3":"PER","NDCOnBehalfOf":"Peru","ContentType":"NDCSubmission","NDCFileType":"NDC","NDCLanguage":"Spanish","EncodedAbsUrl":"https://www4.unfccc.int/sites/ndcstaging/PublishedDocuments/Peru%20First/iNDC%20Perú%20castellano.pdf","NDCSubmissionDate":"25/07/2016 12:00:00 AM"}`

Comment: Also revised above in the question!

Comment: I think I found out what happens: it also translates the % from the space unicode (%20) from the input link into unicode, so that spaces read (%2520) which breaks the link. The ú is actually correctly encoded now. Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Try URL-encoding the [ú](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00fa/index.htm) too. If the remote site uses Latin-1 for file names, try `%FA`; if they use UTF-8, that's `%C3%BA`.

Comment: Conversely, try replacing every `%20` with a literal space, then URL-encoding the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL is only partially encoded. Try replacing every `%20` with a literal space and *then* URL-encoding the whole thing.

```py
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        try:
            head, tail = url.rsplit('/', 1)
            url = '%s/%s' % (head, urllib.parse.quote(tail.replace('%20', ' ')))
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

The difference between `urllib.parse.quote` and `urllib.parse.quote_plus` is that the latter will replace spaces with `+`, whereas the former will URL-encode them back to `%20`.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee, for your help. This worked properly! What also worked was taking the links from the list of dictionaries and saving it with the last part of the URL in an unquoted format. And then quote it again before downloading. But that seems like a workaround and yours seems to be much cleaner!